# How to find the Depth of The "GENERAL TREE" In php?

Tags: php, data-structures

[image: Exapmple Image]

### **About GENERAL TREE**

**A general tree is a data structure in that each node can have infinite number of children.**

Data Will Save In then DB Like Below

[image]

Comment: Homework? Please read this on how to post a good question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you really work on a possibly infinite tree, you cannot use deterministic computers. You also need a row for `A` as a child with no parent. As long as it is a finite tree, you can do this either in PHP or with SQL. Please clarify your question.

Comment: ok. lets have a row for A with no parent.I need Php code for that..